# writing differential equation into state space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control

i have 2 equations of second order that model the same system and i have to model with state variables

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+3y(t)+2\frac{dz}{dt}+z(t)=U_1(t)$$
$$4y(t)+\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}+3\frac{dz}{dt}+4z(t)=U_2(t)$$

For first equation
$${x}_1 = 3y(t)$$
$$\dot{x}_1 = 2\frac{dy}{dt} =x_2$$
$$\dot{x}_2 = \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=x_3$$
How i write this for z variable?
$${x}_4 = z(t)$$
$$\dot{x}_4 = 2\frac{dz}{dt}=x_3$$

For second equation:
I guees have to reuse the terms for first equation, like this:
$${x}_1 = 4y(t)$$
$${x}_4 = 4z(t)$$
$$\dot{x}_4 = 3\frac{dz}{dt}=x_5$$
$$\dot{x}_5 = \frac{d^2z}{dt^2}$$

Then i do the definition of the state variables and the construction of the array, but I need to know if my approach is well

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost right. Forget about the coefficients and just define $x_1 = y$, $x'_1 = x_2 = y'$. For $z$ do just the same: $x_3 = z$, and $x'_3 = x_4 = z'$. Then plug this information into **both** equations. You need as many state variables as the maximum order of-differentiation for *each* dependent variable, i.e., in your case you need six state variables.

Comment: Just 4 variables are required. You don't need $x_3$ and $x_6$.

Comment: You're certainly right. Fixed. Thanks for pointing out @obareey.